# Creating a deep copy of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a deep copy of a `div`. What I mean is that when the cloned copy of the `div` changes color, then the original `div` should change color as well.

What happens in the clone or in the original, should also happen in other one. Here's a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lr1wb2u/)

```js
let clonedEle = $(".one").clone();
    
clonedEle.insertAfter(".one");
    
$(".one").click(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
});
```

```css
.one {
    background-color: red;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="one">
    
</div>
```

My goal is to get both `div`s blue when we click either one. In this example, only one of the `div`s becomes blue when you click on them instead of both at the same time. How do I achieve this?

Comment: `$('.one').css("background-color", "blue");`. What you're asking for could only be done making your `div` a custom element that reacts whenever its style attribute changes, but it can easily be simulated.

Comment: Use $(".one").css("background-color", "blue"); it will work.

Comment: On a side note, [_deep copy_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy) of an object doesn't relate to the original object in any way. The two structures are different from each other, entirely.

Comment: just use `$('.one').css("background-color", "blue")` instead of `$(this).css("background-color", "blue")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a sample of how you could solve this using a customized built-in element:

```js
class MyDiv extends HTMLDivElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.addEventListener('click', () => {
      this.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: #999');
    })
  }
  
  static get observedAttributes() { return ['style'] }
  
  attributeChangedCallback(attr, oldVal, newVal) {
    switch (attr) {
      case 'style':
        if (oldVal === newVal) break; // avoid infinite loops
        const myDivs = document.querySelectorAll('[is="my-div"]');
        for (const div of myDivs) { div.setAttribute('style', newVal) };
        break;
    }
  }
}

customElements.define('my-div', MyDiv, { extends: 'div' });

cloneBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  let theDiv = e.target.nextElementSibling.cloneNode(true);
  document.body.appendChild(theDiv);
})
```

```html
<button type="button" id="cloneBtn">Clone the div</button>
<div is="my-div">my div</div>
```

Try changing the `style` attribute of any of the `my-div`elements in the developer tools of your browser. You'll see that any inline style you give to `my-div` is automatically applied to any other `my-div` on the document as well.

Comment: I have one question why are you using `is` rather than `class`?

Comment: @Shinjo Otherwise it's not a custom element. This is how customized built-in elements work. Without it being a custom element you would'nt be able to setup an `attributeChangedCallback` for changes on the `style` attribute. You could still do this by setting up a `MutationObserver` if you don't want a custom element.

Comment: Though I'm not too sure a `MutationObserver` would be cloned.

Comment: @Shinjo I don't get where you're heading.

Comment: I think I mistook how it works (the way `attributeChangedCallback()` got called when inline styling got implemented). One more question when would `connectedCallback()` got called?

Comment: That depends on how the element is created and is actually quite a complicated thing. Generally `connectedCallback() ` will be called whenever the element becomes part of the DOM, or moved in the DOM. Also it will be called when an element becomes upgraded (which is what happens when the element has already been parsed but only made known later).

Answer (score 2):

$(this) points to only current element and here you wanted to apply color on both the div with same class. So, use $(".one")

Try this -

```
let clonedEle = $(".one").clone();

clonedEle.insertAfter(".one");

$(".one").click(function() {
  $(".one").css("background-color", "blue");
});
```

Hope this will help you.